# Check Id element javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var jewels = new Array()
var index
var rand

var scard = [a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]

    function generateBoard() {

        for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
            jewels[i] = new Array();

            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * scard.length)
            jewels[i] = scard[index]
            console.log("I:" + i + jewels[i])
            var yy = scard.indexOf(scard[index]);
            scard.splice(yy, 1);
        }
    }

    function drawBoard() {

        generateBoard()
        var html = '<div class=Game_Background>'

        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

            rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * jewels.length)
            html += '<div class="' + jewels[rand] + '" id="ship' + i + '" style="top:' + ((i * 12) + 135) + 'px; left:245px;" ></div>'
            jewels.splice(rand, 1);
        }
        var newarray = [a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]
    }
```

here a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3 are css class.I use the newarray because I splice all the array items.Now Suppose the element of ship2 id is b3 and b3 is positioned in newarray[5]. How I check this(the id element is positioned in which number of index in the array)?

Comment: do you want the corresponding class name's postion in array?

Comment: In the example you have not shown what type are all these variables (a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3) and the question is too abstract, add more code to see all the situation and try to be more explicit.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What are you trying to achieve? Please explain more clearly what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: yes anoooooooooooooooop.

Comment: a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3 these are css class and I use images in these class.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jewels = new Array()
var index
var rand

var scard = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"];
var newarray = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"];

drawBoard();



function drawBoard() {


    var html = '<div class=Game_Background>'

    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * scard.length);
        html += '<div class="' + scard[rand] + '" id="ship' + i + '" style="top:' + ((i * 12) + 135) + 'px; left:245px;" ></div>'
        alert(newarray.indexOf(scard[rand]));
        scard.splice(rand, 1);
    }
}

</script>
```